# Nest.js Model Dependency Injection with Mongoose with no constructor

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, zoho

I need to integrate a CRM API with my service in Nest.js. Unfortunately, they require I implement their interface to use a custom persistence layer, in my case, Mongo. Since I'll need to instantiate the resulting class, I can't inject the model as I normally would so I tried using this on the class member variable instead. However, this results in an error that the member variable is undefined.

This is my mongoose model:

```
export type ZohoTokenDocument = ZohoToken & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class ZohoToken {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 255, unique: true })
  user_mail: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 255, unique: true })
  client_id: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 255 })
  refresh_token: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 255 })
  access_token: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 255 })
  grant_token: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, length: 20 })
  expiry_time: string;
}

export const ZohoTokenSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ZohoToken);
```

This is the custom class I'm creating as required by the 3rd party API:

```
export class ZohoStore implements TokenStore {
  @InjectModel(ZohoToken.name)
  private readonly tokenModel: Model<ZohoTokenDocument>;

  async getToken(user, token): Promise<any> {
    const result = await this.tokenModel.findOne({ grant_token: token });
    return result;
  }
...
```

And in my service, I'm just instantiating this class as `new ZohoStore()`, which works fine until the `getToken()` method is called later.

The resulting error is: `"nullTypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined",`, which to me means the `tokenModel` is not being instantiated. Any idea how I can get my model injected into this class without putting it in the constructor, otherwise I can't instantiate it with a zero-arg constructor from my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to use Nest DI system, then you just can't call `new ZohoStore()` by yourself because Nest has no chance to instantiate `ZohoStore`'s dependencies.

You'll need to register it as a provider in some NestJS module and then retrive the instance **created by NestJS** if you want to.

- https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection
- https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#retrieving-instances
- https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Micael's response, you need to do the following:

1. Add the store to the module that will be using DI:

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: ZohoToken.name, schema: ZohoTokenSchema }])],
  exports: [ZohoStore, ZohoService],
  providers: [ZohoStore, ZohoService],
  controllers: [ZohoController]
})
export class ZohoModule {}
```

2. Be sure to add the `@Injectable()` decorator to Store class and use DI to inject model:

```
@Injectable()
export class ZohoStore implements TokenStore {
  constructor(@InjectModel(ZohoToken.name)
  private readonly tokenModel: Model<ZohoTokenDocument>){};
```

3. In the service class, reference `ZohoStore` as follows so when you're ready to use it you just call `this.zohoStore` from the class member variable rather that trying to instantiate it with `new`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ZohoService {
  private zohoStore: ZohoStore;

  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.zohoStore = this.moduleRef.get(ZohoStore);
  }
```